# Split main.bundle.js angular starter

Tags: webpack

I am using https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter for my project and I want to split main.bundle.js in multiple files with predefined names.

For example:

- main.bundle.1.js
- main.bundle.2.js
- main.bundle.3.js
- main.bundle.4.js

Is it possible to make this kind of configuration?